# How to use Math.round on a big deciaml in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a variable in my groovy script that collects a cost value. However the value comes out as 91.7776766667 and I want it to be rounded up so it is displayed as 91.8. How can I change the code below to do this and I am struggling to implement the Math.round feature:

```
def testcost = jsongroups.xxx.cost.flatten().collect { new Math.round(BigDecimal (it)) }

log.info testcost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Math.round() you can use BigDecimal.setScale(scale, roundingMode) on your number directly.

```
def testcost = jsongroups.options.cost.flatten().collect { new BigDecimal (it).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)}
log.info testcost
```

HALF_UP will round .01-.04 to .0 and .05-.09 to .1. Read the JavaDoc of RoundingMode for other rounding possibilities, like HALF_EVEN etc.

Answer (score -1):

Groovy language has a `round()` method which going to round your decimal number to specific decimal place as a parameter.

```
def decimalValue = (Double)91.7776766667
println "Value upto two decimal places >>"+decimalValue.round(2)
```

Output:

```
Value upto two decimal places >>91.78
```

Comment: which version of Java and Groovy are you using? Cause with 2.4.11 JVM: 1.8.0_131 I get groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.math.BigDecimal.round() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2] from your code

Comment: Hey, you are going to round integer number, first, convert it into `Double` then try `round()` on it. I changed above answer please check out.

Comment: For more details please refer [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2010/01/groovy-goodness-round-and-truncate.html)

Comment: Not a good solution: the point is that if you have a BigDecimal and  you convert it to double you might loose precision enough to get the wrong answer after you round it. Rounding a BigDecimal starting you control exactly how the rounding is done, and in some cases you get a better result e.g. 0.145 rounded to 2 figures if you do new BigDecimal("0.145").doubleValue().round(2) you get 0.14 which not what you what if you use HALF_UP.  This happens because groovy to round transformes the Double 0.145  into a 0.14499999999999999... and next makes the imprecise rounding to 0.14.